# How to check in a macro if a field type implements a given interface?

Tags: reflection, haxe

I can reach the ClassType of the field, but there's no equality testing between to ClassType.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ClassType` is defined as follows:

```
typedef ClassType = {> BaseType,
    var kind : ClassKind;
    var isInterface : Bool;
    var superClass : Null<{ t : Ref<ClassType>, params : Array<Type> }>;
    var interfaces : Array<{ t : Ref<ClassType>, params : Array<Type> }>;
    var fields : Ref<Array<ClassField>>;
    var statics : Ref<Array<ClassField>>;
    //var dynamic : Null<Type>;
    //var arrayAccess : Null<Type>;
    var constructor : Null<Ref<ClassField>>;
    var init : Null<TypedExpr>;
    var overrides : Array<Ref<ClassField>>;
}
```

And `BaseType` (which it inherits from) contains `module` and `name` fields, so you should be able to check the module and name for each item in the `interfaces` list. Alternately, you can rely on `Ref.toString()` to return the fully-qualified name:

```
for(interfaceRef in Context.getLocalClass().get().interfaces) {
    if(interfaceRef.t.toString() == "flash.events.IEventDispatcher") {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Comment: That's my present solution, but I really dislike the string comparison.

Comment: You could probably resolve the type based on the string. And given that this is the format provided by Context.getLocalClass(), any "alternate" solution would do that under the hood.